# covert ascii to decimal python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ascii

I have a data pandas DataFrame, where one of the columns is filled with ascii characters. I'm trying to convert this column from ascii to decimal, where, for example, the following string should be converted from in Hex:

```
313533313936393239382e323834303638
```

to:

```
1531969298.284068
```

I've tried

```
outf['data'] = outf['data'].map`(`lambda x: bytearray.fromhex(x).decode())
```

as well as

```
outf['data'] = outf['data'].map(lambda x: ascii.fromhex(x).decode())
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 8: invalid start byte
```

I'm not sure where the problem manifests itself. I have a txt file and a sample of its contents are as follows:

```
data time 
313533313936393239382e32373737343800 1531969299.283273000 
313533313936393239382e32373838303400 1531969299.284253000      
313533313936393239382e32373938353700 1531969299.285359000
```

When the data was normal integers the the lambda would work fine where I used:

```
outf['data'] = outf['data'].astype(str)
outf['data'] = outf['data'].str[:-2:]
outf['data'] = outf['data'].map(lambda x: bytearray.fromhex(x).decode())
outf['data'] = outf['data'].astype(int)
```

, however now it says there's something wrong with the encoding.

I've looked on Stackoverflow, but perhaps I wasn't able to find something similar.
However, it hasn't worked. If someone where to help me out, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: `out['data'].map(lambda x:  bytearray.fromhex(x).decode()).astype(float)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I'm using the 'outf['data'] = outf['data'].astype(np.float64)' in the next line.
However, when I just tried your recommendation, it gave me the same error, as before, mainly: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 8: invalid start byte'

Comment: Could you print out the problematic value and its type ?

Comment: Please see the edited question

Comment: @habitual_programmer This may be bad data.  Can you present data duplicating this error?  Thank you.

Comment: @ScottBoston Sorry it was a 400MB data file that I'm working with You were right, it was bad data at one point that was causing the issue. Thank you both for your help. I personally prefer Scott's solution, so I'm not sure whether I should simply close the question, or accept, Ketouem's as I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` with a lambda function for bytearray.fromhex and `astype` to float.

```
out['data'].map(lambda x: bytearray.fromhex(x).decode()).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Such lambda would do the trick:

```
>>> f = lambda v: float((bytearray.fromhex(v)))
>>> f('313533313936393239382e323834303638')
1531969298.284068
```

Note that the use of numpy's [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) hinted by [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston) in the comment section may be better performance-wise.

Comment: Please see my response to Scott